# How to create several individual emails from Excel sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, email, outlook

I want to grab data from specified worksheets in an Excel workbook and then generate individual emails from each individual sheet.

Right now, the code will generate the first email from the first sheet then cycle through the remaining tabs without creating additional emails. I can confirm that the code is progressing beyond the first sheet via a `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name` check.

I am leveraging Ron DeBruin's `RangetoHtml` function in a separate module.

```vb
Sub ClientEvent_Email_Generation()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim count_row, count_col As Integer
Dim Event_Table_Data As Range
Dim Event2_Table_Data As Range
Dim strl As String, STR2 As String, STR3 As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim I As Integer

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    WS.Activate

    If WS.Name <> "DATA INPUT" And WS.Name <> "FORMATTED DATA TABLE" And WS.Name <> "REP CODE MAPPING TABLE" And WS.Name <> "IDEAS TAB" And WS.Name <> "REFERENCE" Then

        count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.Range("A10", Range("a10").End(xlDown)))
        count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.Range("A10", Range("a10").End(xlToRight)))

        Set Event_Table_Data = WS.Cells.Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col)) 
        Set Event2_Table_Data = Sheets("w61").Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col)) 

        str1 = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Times New Roman>" & _
          "Hello " & Range("L3").Value & ",<br><br>The following account(s) listed below appear to have an upcoming event(s)<br>"
        STR2 = "<br> Included are suggestions for an activity which may fit your client's needs.<br>"
        STR3 = "<br> You may place an order, or contact us for alternate ideas if these don't fit your client."

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = WS.Range("l4").Value
            .cc = ""
            .bcc = ""
            .Subject = "Upcoming Event In Your Clients' Account(s)"
            .display
            .HTMLBody = str1 & RangetoHTML(Event_Table_Data) & STR2 & RangetoHTML(Event2_Table_Data)& STR3 & .HTMLBody
            .SEND
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing

        MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name ‘Used for testing purposes only

    End If
Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: The `On Error Resume Next` will result in swallowing errors which might be occurring. I suggest you remove that (along with `On Error Goto 0` while troubleshooting.

Comment: You destroy the OutMail and OutApp objects at the end of each loop, i.e. the first cycle runs normally, and the second and next refers to destroyed objects. But you have disabled error messages and you can't see what's going on.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to delete lines `Set OutMail = Nothing` and `Set OutApp = Nothing`

Comment: `Cells(count_row, count_col)` should probably be `Cells(count_row + 9, count_col)` in setting data ranges.

Comment: Rob_M and Алексей Р. Thanks for the suggestions. I removed the On Error Resume Next via comment block and ran the code. The code still creates an email based off of the first sheet but then returns an "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" message on the .To = WS.Range("l4").Value line which is used to populate the email address from a cell value within the sheet.

Comment: Move the line `Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)` to inside the loop before `With OutMail`